# How can I prove $n - 2\sqrt{n} = \Theta(n)$

Tags: asymptotics

I want to prove the following $$n - 2\sqrt{n} = \Theta(n)$$

It's $n - 2\sqrt{n} \leq n = O(n)$

How can I prove the same for $\Omega(n)$

Comment: Whats the difference between $\Theta$ and $O$, and $\Omega$?

Comment: It is $\Theta(n)$ is if its $O$ and $\Omega$ at the same time.

Comment: you should define these things because as far as I know, only $O$ is standard notation.

Comment: @MSEoris https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations

Comment: @MSEoris They are three distinct notations and are quite common.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$
n - 2\sqrt{n} \geq \frac 12 n \iff\\
n \geq 4 \sqrt{n} \iff\\
\sqrt{n} \geq 4 \iff\\
n \geq 16
$$
That is, for $n \geq 16$, we have $n - 2\sqrt{n} \geq k n$ for all $n \geq 16$ when $k = 1/2$.  Thus, we have $n- 2\sqrt{n} = \Omega(n)$.

---

Alternatively, we can concisely prove that $n - 2\sqrt{n} = \Theta(n)$ (or, in particular, that $n -2\sqrt n \sim n$) by simply noting that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n - 2\sqrt{n}}{n} = 1
$$